# Objective C and peer to peer communication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, p2p

I want to build 2 apps:
1) iPhone objective c app.
2) Windows executable app.

The iPhone app and the executable app should both be able to communicate from time to time with a remote server (every few minutes for example).
Now, I also want to be able (when needed) to communicate directly between the iPhone app and the executable application.
I assume that in order to communicate in such way, I will need to do peer-to-peer communication.

Am I right? can somebody direct me on this issue? Is there already an existing example that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial here http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/
is a great starter for bonjour. If you're working with iOS 5 though, you'll have to upgrade the code yourself. Not a big problem though since the compiler will help you with it :)

Answer (score 3):

Look into Bonjour Networking.  Its from Apple and is great for peer-to-peer.  And it works with Windows

Comment: What do you mean works with Windows? Suppose my windows client is written with Delphi - how the Bonjour Networking comes in place? The app is an iPhone app. Is this Bonjour service available on for iPhone API?

Comment: Google it. There's all kinds of info out there.